# Минимальный накрывающий круг С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

На плоскости даны n точек с координатами. Необходимо накрыть по крайней мере k из них кругом **с центром на оси Ox**. Найдите наименьший возможный радиус такого круга с точностью до 10^-3.

Решение нужно на С++ со сложностью не более О(n^2).

Знаю про алгоритм Вельцля. Также пыталась гуглить. Все найденные алгоритмы не учитывают, что центр круга должен лежать на оси Ох. Как их переделать под свою задачу - уже сломала голову.

Функция, которую мне предложил ChatGPT (передаются точки и количество точек, которое надо покрыть), но также не учитывает центр на оси Ох.

```
double getDistance(const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2) {
    double dx = p1.first - p2.first;
    double dy = p1.second - p2.second;
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

pair<double, pair<int, int>> getMinimalCircle(const vector<pair<int, int>>& points, int numPoints) {

    vector<pair<int, int>> selectedPoints(points.begin(), points.begin() + numPoints);
    random_shuffle(selectedPoints.begin(), selectedPoints.end());

    pair<int, int> center = selectedPoints[0];
    double radius = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; i++) {
        if (getDistance(center, selectedPoints[i]) > radius) {
            center = selectedPoints[i];
            radius = 0.0;
        
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (getDistance(center, selectedPoints[j]) > radius) {
                    center.first = (selectedPoints[i].first + selectedPoints[j].first) / 2;
                    center.second = 0;
                    radius = getDistance(center, selectedPoints[j]);
                
                    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                        if (getDistance(center, selectedPoints[k]) > radius) {
                            center.first = ((selectedPoints[i].first + selectedPoints[j].first) / 2 + selectedPoints[k].first) / 2;
                            center.second = 0;
                            radius = getDistance(center, selectedPoints[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return make_pair(radius, center);
}
```

Comment: Скажите - а если вам дан радиус круга, вы можете за O(n) посчитать максимальное количество точек, которое он может накрыть, если центр где-то на OX?

Comment: вы знаете линейный алгоритм для описанной мной подзадачи или предполагаете, что он есть? Я пока только предполагаю. И ещё вопрос - каков диапазон координат?

Answer (score 0):

Если дан радиус круга `R`, то для каждой точки мы можем посчитать, в каком диапазоне позиций центра круга по `X` она будет лежать в круге. Таким образом, образуется не более `N` интервалов (часть точек за полосой полуширины `R` никогда не попадут в круг и не образуют интервалов). Мы можем отсортировать их концы за `O(NlogN)` и найти отрезок по оси `OX`, при расположении центра круга в котором круг данного радиуса покроет наибольшее количество точек. Для нас важно только это количество точек.

Понятно, что зависимость количества точек от радиуса монотонная - значит, мы можем применить метод бинарного поиска по радиусу, пока не достигнем нужной точности в 0.001, обеспечив `k` точек в круге.

Сложность получается `O(NlogN*log(CoordinateRange))`

Если первую задачу можно решить за линейное время, то ещё лучше получится.

---

Расшифровка подзадачи с интервалами:

Точка `(x,y)`, если `abs(y)<=R`, может входить в круги с центром в диапазоне

```
X0=x-sqrt(R^2-y^2)...X1=x+sqrt(R^2-y^2)
```

Добавляем в вектор или список пару `<X0, 1>` и пару `<X1, -1>`.

Обработав все точки, сортируем список по первому элементу, при равенстве учитываем второй элемент.

Ставим счётчик в 0, идём по списку, на каждом шаге добавляя к счётчику второй элемент пары. Максимальное значение счётчика - максимальное количество покрытых точек. Само значение координаты роли не играет, но в принципе отрезок доступен.

---

Бинарный поиск по ответу:

```
lo = 0;
hi = 2000;
while (hi - lo > 0.0001) {
    m = (lo + hi) / 2;
    cnt = points_in_circle(m); //это функция с кодом, описанным выше
    if (cnt < k)
        lo = m;
    else
        hi = m;
}
return lo;  //искомый радиус
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, как работает бинарный поиск по решению? Берем R = R0 (максимальной разнице координат), считаем, сколько максимум точек может содержать такой круг. Если больше k - делим радиус пополам, опять считаем макс. количество точек для R0/2. Если больше k - переходим к R0/4 и продолжаем, если меньше - переходим к 3/4*R0 и продолжаем. Так до тех пор, пока шаг не станет меньше 0.001

Comment: Добавил описание.

Comment: В вашем примере минимальный радиус - корень из двух, не единица.

Comment: Вы молодец, что все реализовали, это не так уж просто. Вероятно, неверно выбран R0. Ещё момент - нужна разновидность бинарного поиска leftmost

Comment: Начальное значение R0 как установили?

Comment: Что-то такое: `max(abs(ymax), abs(ymin)) + (xmax-xmin)`

Comment: Радиус может быть больше, чем любая координата по модулю, для вашего примера это видно

Comment: Проще вначале поставить с запасом и не нарушать ход поиска. Бинарный поиск сделан так, что ищет [наименьший радиус](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binary_search_algorithm&section=5)?

Comment: А если у второй точки y +1000?

Comment: Отлично решение! Я пытался обойтись без поиска по результату, но ничего лучше чем *NNlogN* не получил. Это решение очень быстрое.